# Moodle not running not giving an error and not loggin an error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, rhel5, moodle

I've moved a Moodle install from one machine to an identical machine and now it won't run. It gives no error on the screen, logs no error anywhere I can find, it just returns a completely blank page. The server is running PHP without issues and I've verified this with a simple helloworld-style PHP program that just print phpInfo();

When I say the two servers are identical I really do mean it. They are on identical hardlware bought at the same time and have the identical OS (RHEL5) with the identical packages, patches and upgrades installed.

I'm completely at sea on this one since there isn't even an error message to check for! In desperation I disabled SELinux but that didn't help either.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this, or does anyone have any suggestions I could try?

Thanks,

Bart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out my packages weren't QUITE as identical as I thought - was missing just one, but it was an important one, pho-mysql! I had PHP, and I had MySQL, but not php-mysql. I'm shocked that Moodle failed without an error of any kind and returned just a blank page with an HTTP response code of 200 OK - surely there's nothing OK about failing to talk to the DB!

Anyhow, should anyone else stumble upon this problem, this was the solution for me.

Bart.

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that Moodle has snagged some part of the first machine's host information (hostname or ip address perhaps) into its configuration somewhere.

I've never done a move of an application before, unless it was a dump of its database, install the app on machine two, then import the database.

Might also explore the [Moodle docs](http://docs.moodle.org/en/Main_Page).

Comment: I've gone through the Moodle config to check for anything in there - everything that's set is set correctly.

Comment: that was my guess - not sure where to go next - maybe the Moodle docs? http://docs.moodle.org/en/Main_Page